# Node build artefacts in Docker container fails to run because of source-map-support/register

Tags: javascript, node.js, docker, webpack

I'm using [Backpack](https://github.com/jaredpalmer/backpack) to build my node app. When running the app locally, the app itself and the build artefacts are doing okay. But when I move the build results to a Docker image and try to run it, I get the following errors:

```
Error: Cannot find module 'source-map-support/register'
Require stack:
- /home/app/main.js
at Function.Module._resolveFilename (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:815:15)
at Function.Module._load (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:667:27)
at Module.require (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:887:19)
at require (internal/modules/cjs/helpers.js:74:18)
at Object.<anonymous> (/home/app/main.js:1:1)
at Module._compile (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:999:30)
at Object.Module._extensions..js (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:1027:10)
at Module.load (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:863:32)
at Function.Module._load (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:708:14)
at Function.executeUserEntryPoint [as runMain] (internal/modules/run_main.js:60:12) {
code: 'MODULE_NOT_FOUND',
requireStack: [ '/home/app/main.js' ]
```

My Dockerfile:

```
FROM node:12.21-alpine

ENV NODE_ENV=production

RUN mkdir -p /home/app

COPY ./build /home/app

WORKDIR /home

CMD ["node", "./app/main.js"]
```

What am I missing? Are there other alternatives for Backpack? Basically, I want to build my app first, move the artefacts into a Docker image and then run that. I'm not looking to build inside an image.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are missing `node_modules`.
You have to copy node_modules to container `COPY ./node_modules /home/app/node_modules`
Or  install it during the docker build (remember to copy package.json and package-lock.json) `RUN npm ci`.
If it is a local development env, you can choose the first option. But if not, a better way is second one.

Comment: I tried it and it works. Could you help me in understanding why? My thought was that after I build the project, I will get everything that I need in the build folder. Why is there a need for `node_modules`? I have the prior knowledge of using `react-scripts build` which packages the app nicely without the need of the `node_modules`.

Comment: @Vivere Node_modules contains all dependencies that you defined in package.json. Container is clean environment it contains only that what is in image definition in docker file. To run your application you need node_modules and it have to appear in container. To do that you can install on container during the build or copy it, like rest of the files.